# Disappearance of items from contentplaceholder on item click

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, master-pages

i am creating a master page in which there are two ContentPlaceHolders. ContentPlaceHolders1 is for the menu in which there are hyperlinks and in the other ContentPlaceHolders which is ContentPlaceHolders3, there the selected hyperlink will open its page. the problem is that the menu at the left apperars but when i click one of the hyperlink from it the page opens in ContentPlaceHolders3 but ther whole menu from ContentPlaceHolders1 disappears. picture.aspx and sample.aspx are the pages which are to be opened in ContentPlaceHolder3.

here is the code for different pages:

admin_panel.master:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="admin_panel.master.cs" Inherits="admin_panel" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>

<form id="form1" runat="server">

        <table style="font-family: Arial">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="width: 800px; height: 80px; background-color: #3399FF; text-align: center">
                    <h1>WebSite Header</h1>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="height: 500px; background-color: #66FFFF; width: 150px">
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </td>
                <td style="height: 500px; background-color: #9999FF; width: 650px">
                    <h3>Content</h3>
                    <div>
                        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder3" runat="server">
                        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>    
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

pictures.aspx:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" EnableEventValidation="false" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="pictures.aspx.cs" Inherits="pictures" MasterPageFile="~/admin_panel.master"%>


        <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder3" Runat="Server">

            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="200px" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" Height="200px" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" Height="200px" /><br />
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />

        </asp:Content>
```

sample:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="sample.aspx.cs" Inherits="sample"  MasterPageFile="~/admin_panel.master"%>

    <asp:Content ID="nil" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder3" runat="server">

        <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" style="height: 26px" />
    </div>

    </asp:Content>
```

admin.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/admin_panel.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="admin.aspx.cs" Inherits="admin" %>


<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server" >
    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" NavigateUrl="~/pictures.aspx" runat="server">Click Me</asp:HyperLink><br />
    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" NavigateUrl="~/sample.aspx" runat="server">Click Me 2...</asp:HyperLink>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason being is that when you open the page sample.aspx what you get is a combination of Master Page + Sample Page. So nowhere we have ContentPlaceHolder1 contents defined. i.e. Not in sample.aspx and not in admin_panel.master. That's why it is blank. Instead of Specifying menu in admin, you can put it in master page. Like:

```
   <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
     <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" NavigateUrl="~/pictures.aspx" runat="server">Click Me</asp:HyperLink><br />
     <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" NavigateUrl="~/sample.aspx" runat="server">Click Me 2...         </asp:HyperLink>
   </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

That should solve your problem. :)